# How do you find the sum of everything inside a list when objects in the list are classes

Tags: python

Hello I want to find the sum of everything inside a list, however when I look it up they show examples of numbers inside lists. But I have classes inside lists.

Here is dogclass.py

```
class dog:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Here is dogs.py (I made dogs.py so I dont have to define all these dogs I will make on my main file)

```
from dogclass import dog
baba = dog("Baba", 8)
jojo = dog("Jojo", 3)
```

And here is main.py

```
import dogs as d
dogs = [d.baba, d.jojo]
average_combine = dogs[0].age + dogs[1].age
dogs_age_average = round(average_combine / len(dogs))
```

This code works just fine and I could do it this way
But If i have a hundred dogs, I will have to do this a hundred times                   And I don't want to do that.
Is there a way that I can find the sum of the ages without having to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generator expression (a list comprehension without the list-materialization step) to grab the `age` value from each object in the list, then sum the resulting list:

```
age_sum = sum(d.age for d in dogs)
```

Comment: No need to create the inner list, it's wasting both time and memory. `sum` accepts 
 generator objects: `sum(d.age for d in dogs)`

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks, I had no idea what the name was :)

Answer (score 0):

One line solution, you probably want to read up on Python's [list comprehensions](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

```
dogs_age_average = round(sum(dog.age for dog in dogs) / len(dogs))
```

Comment: but there is no list comprehension in this suggested solution.

Comment: @SimonChoi There's an important difference between sum(dog.age for dog in dogs) and sum([dog.age for dog in dogs]) (notice the square brackets). The first one is a generator and is more efficient than the second one, which also creates a list which occupies space in memory.

Comment: @DeepSpace You're right, in this case it would be a generator comprehension I guess. I've only ever heard of them being referred to as list comprehensions, even when using sets or other data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension to sum up all the dog's ages:

```
class dog:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

baba = dog("Baba", 8)
jojo = dog("Jojo", 3)


dogs = [baba, jojo]
average_combine = sum([d.age for d in dogs])
dogs_age_average = round(average_combine / len(dogs))
print(dogs_age_average)
```

Result:

```
6
```

Comment: No need to create the inner list, it's wasting both time and memory. `sum` accepts 
 generator objects: `sum(d.age for d in dogs)`

Answer (score 0):

If sum:

```
sum(d.age for d in dogs)
```

If average, better make it float if not want to lose digits after integer:

```
sum(float(d.age) for d in dogs)/len(dogs)
```

Comment: Are you still using Python 2?

Comment: No need to create the inner list, it's wasting both time and memory. `sum` accepts 
 generator objects: `sum(d.age for d in dogs)`

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will help you to do that easily.

```
class dog:
def __init__(self,name,age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
  
# creating list       
list = [] 

# appending instances to list 
list.append( dog('a', 40) )
list.append( dog('b', 40) )
list.append( dog('c', 44) )
list.append( dog('x', 50) )
average_combine= 0 
for obj in list:
  average_combine=+ obj.age
dogs_age_average = round(average_combine / len(list))
print(dogs_age_average)
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, as it's the name of a built-in (`list()`) function.